# smtp Connection could not be established in postman - laravel

Tags: laravel, api, postman, email-verification

I am trying to make an api authentication system with email verification but i get this error in postman:

> "message": "Connection could not be established with host
> smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
> tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:25 (A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond.\r\n)",

This is my env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25 (and 587 , 2525)
MAIL_USERNAME=3aeeeeeeeeee87a
MAIL_PASSWORD=2104eeeeeeeeee9
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I have run:

- `php artisan config:clear`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- Restart XAMPP

`mail.php` values are as same as `.env` file but still get the same error, how can I solve this?

Comment: any firewall setup?

Comment: @JuanEizmendi no nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You must be entering the email in the wrong format(in input), set the validation of the email, or enter the email in a proper format and then try it will work.